# Recursive function python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'am trying to write a recursive function that returns a list of n first squared numbers.
For example if n is 5 it would return `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]`
I wrote a function but it didn't get me exactly what I wanted, it gave me a list of successive squared numbers for example n is 5 : `[0, 1, 2, 4, 16, 256,65536 ]` 
Here's my function :

```
def premiersCarresRec(n) :
  res = [] 
  if n == 2 :
   res.append(1)       
   res.append(4)
  else :
   tmp = premiersCarresRec(n - 1)      
   res.append(tmp[0] * tmp[0])
  return res
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best practice for recursion, but it seems that this is what you meant to do.

```
lst = []
def square_rec(n):
    if n == 0:
        lst.append(0)
        return 0
    else:
        lst.append(n**2)
    return square_rec(n-1)

square_rec(5)

print lst
>>>[25, 16, 9, 4, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the list with result around in the recursion:

```
def squares(n, res=None):
    if res is None:
        res = []
    res.append(n * n)
    if n > 0:
        squares(n-1, res)
    return res[::-1]

>>> squares(5)  
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```